# I need help to identify this SOT563 IC

Tags: identification

Can someone help me to identify this SOT563 IC? It might be an operational amplifier. The resistor is 0402.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's an op amp? Show a picture of the surrounding circuitry to give us something to work with. Like I wrote in the answer to your previous question, it's hard confirm the right part if we know nothing about the connections.

Comment: Could it be SOT363:  
https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/ma  https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/s/i/sip32431_rc_vishay.pdf

Comment: @hennep The markings don't match: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Distribution-Switches_Vishay-Intertech-SIP32431DR3-T1GE3_C141606.html

Answer (score 1):

The markings and package match with an [Onsemi NST3904DXV6T1G Dual Bipolar Transistor](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/308/1/NST3904DXV6T1_D-2318607.pdf).

[image]

I couldn't find pictures of the part, but there are other parts with the same packaging made by Onsemi that use the same markings style with a 90° rotated date code, for example the [BC847BPDXV6T1G](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Bipolar-Transistors-BJT_onsemi-BC847BPDXV6T1G_C152304.html).

[image]